# Netbean does not install

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to start this MOOC here: http://mooc.fi/courses/2013/programming-part-1/, and it instructs me to install Netbean. I have downloaded JDK as instructed on the website, and then tried to install Netbean, but the installer would not open. What happens is the computer appears as if it is loading (blue circle on Windows 8), but never actually opens the installer.

I have an intel i5-4210Y CPU at 1.50GHz, 8gb of RAM, and 64 bit OS. I have 743mb remaining on my C drive.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the task actually running (check your task manager). How many instances are running?
This looks more like a question for netbeans forums though.

Answer (score 0):

A easy way to "Install" Netbeans if you are having issues with the installer is to use the zip.

It can easily be found here:
https://netbeans.org/downloads/zip.html

Depending on what you want to do you will select the package you want. Im guessing since you're taking an online course in java, then you are not a professional programmer, so you wont need JavaEE. I think your best bet is to download "netbeans-8.1-201510222201-javaee.zip" and extract it to a place you can find it, maybe your desktop, or Program Files if you are an admin. Your executable will be in the BIN folder after you extract netbeans. You will see netbeans.exe, netbeans (this is a linux sh file, you don't need it), and netbeans64.exe.

Depending on what system you have, run the appropriate application.

- netbeans.exe for x86 windows
- netbeans for linux
- netbeans64.exe for x64 windows.